# no puedo vincular firebase

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin

tengo un problema, firebase me pide que meta cierto codigo en una ruta:

Archivo de Gradle de nivel de raíz (nivel de proyecto) (/build.gradle):

pero esa ruta me lleva a un build.gradle que no se parece en nada al que pone en firebase

AYUDA!!! NO ENCUENTRO SOLUCIÓN

Lo que me pide firebase:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
}
```

Lo que me sale:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

Comment: La configuración que tratas de realizar debes agregarla en el archivo build.gradle que se encuentra en la raíz de tu proyecto no en el del directorio app/ , revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

es bastante confuso eso si, a mi me pasa todo el tiempo que no diferencio bien esos archivos.
A ver si te puedo ayudar.

Sobre la derecha en AndroidStudio, con tu proyecto abierto, deberías poder ver una pestaña que se llama Project, y sobre el cuadro donde se muestran los diferentes archivos y  carpetas deberías poder ver un deplegable, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces teniendo seleccionada la pestaña Project, y Android en el desplegable, en el cuadro que te muestra los archivos deberías poder encontrar la carpeta Gradle Scripts, y creo que el archivo que buscas es el primero que aparece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En tu proyecto Android, debes tener dos archivos `build.gradle`, uno en la raíz del proyecto `<proyecto>/build.gradle` y otro dentro del directorio `app/`, en el primero es donde debes realizar los cambios.

Para ubicar los archivos de una mejor forma, cambia la configuración del explorador de archivos de `Android` a `Project`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que los SDKs de Firebase puedan acceder a los valores de tu archivo de configuración `google-services.json`, necesitas el complemento de los servicios de Google para Gradle (google-services).

Agrega el complemento de los servicios de Google como dependencia de buildscript en el archivo de Gradle (`<project>/build.gradle`) de nivel de raíz (nivel de proyecto):

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
      // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
      google()  // Google's Maven repository
      mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }

    dependencies {
      ...

      // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
  ...

  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
  }
}
```

Agrega el complemento de los servicios de Google en el archivo de Gradle (generalmente //build.gradle) del módulo (nivel de app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'

    // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    ...
}
```

Revisa:

[**Agrega Firebase al proyecto de Android**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es)